# Strange character appearing in CSV file after import into R (†)

Tags: r, csv

I've used read.csv to import a file into R. When I View the dataframe, the strings appear the same as in the CSV file I imported. Some of the strings in the dataframe were not behaving properly when referenced.

When I then write.csv to export the file, a strange character appears where there were spaces in the strings that were not behaving properly when referenced. It looks like this: †

I've tried specifying fileEncoding in the write.csv function, but because those strings are not behaving for analysis after import, it appears the problem happens due to how it is imported and not how it is exported.

This is how I am reading in the data and what I'm doing prior to export.

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")

df = subset(df, select = - 
c(Email,First_Name,Last_Name,X.removed,X.removed.1, X.removed.2))

write.csv(df, file ="data.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")
```

When I was trying to reference the strings unsuccessfully, this is the code I was using.

```
df$Other <- sub("^$", "0", df$Other)

df$Other <- sub("Other Answer", "1", df$Other)

df$Other <- as.numeric(df$Other)
```

I then got an error message saying NAs were introduced by coercion because the sub function was not able to find "Other Answer." I ended up using the below code to successfully make df$Other a binary, numeric variable.

```
df$Other[df$Other!="0"] <- 1
```

There is another column that contains the same string that remains a factor (and is not changed to be binary and numeric). When I export the dataframe using write.csv, this strange character appears in the space between "Other" and "Answer" in the exported CSV file for that factored column. It says "Other†Answer."

This is true for two other columns as well, and the character is NOT only in the first space of the string, it also appears in the second space in a string but not in the first space for that string. Other strings import and export just fine.

I am expecting my exported CSV file to have spaces in three different strings where one space (in each) has been replaced with †. I am also expecting those strings to import with spaces and not †, such that I am able to reference them to use the sub function.

Example: "Other Answer" instead of "Other†Answer," "Different Other Answer" instead of "Different Other†Answer" and "Comment Here" instead of "Comment†Here."

I would love to know why this is happening, but I would also be fine with just knowing how to address it so that the strings appear the way I expect upon export to CSV. I've already found a workaround for the sub function.

Comment: Try reading it in with `read_csv` or `fread` and writing with `write_csv` and `fwrite` from the `readr` and `data.table` libraries respectively. This might solve your issue? Another thing I see, is that your column `df$Other` seems to be a character type, but in the line `df$Other[df$Other!="0"] <- 1` you are replacing it with a numeric type, which may cause issues (unless it is being automatically coerced).

Anyway, it's kind of hard to give advice for this question, because we do not have the underlying data. If you can provide, we can help more.

Comment: Try running `tools::showNonASCIIfile("data.csv")`.  This will let you know if you have any non-ASCII characters in the original file, and where they are if you do.